# Make shortened and long urls play together on the same domain (RewriteRule)

Tags: mod-rewrite, regex, url

Long story short, I want to have both `example.com/aJ5` and `example.com/any-other-url` working together.
I'm using apache and not very good at writing regex.

I have already a global `RewriteRule` which sends everything to the app entry point.
What I need is to tell apache `if length($path) is <= 5 chars` then rewrite to another location.

I know I can use `{1,5}` like syntax in regex, but don't really know if it's what I'm looking for.

I'd like to implement this at web-server level rather than php level. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that the `-` character will not be included in short URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,5} 
RewriteRule ^ /app-entry-point?url=%1 [L]
```

This is untested but something like this should work. Essentially you're passing a condition if `REQUEST_URI` is something like `/abc12`, control switches to whatever handler you want. It will skip URLs over 5 characters or that include the 'slug' character "-" or an underscore.

`%1`, the last `RewriteCond` backreference, will be expanded to the short URL. Put this above your other rules to enforce this first -- with the `[L]` flag it will stop rewriting URLs and pass control to the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/.{1,5}$
 RewriteRule ...
```

This will match any request between one and five characters in length, and will run the following RewriteRule. Anything longer then that will not run the RewriteRule. The REQUEST_URI variable is what the browser passed to the web-server. The same could be handled in a single RewriteRule, but the above allows chaining if you need it.

```
 ^/.{1,5}$
```

^ = Matches the start of the string
/ = Just matches a forward slash
. = Matches any one character that isn't a newline
{1,5} = Informs the regex engine to match the previous character 1-5 times
$ = Matches the end-of-line character

The `/.{1,5}$` construct tells the regex engine to match any string of size 1-5 that is immediately followed by the end-of-line character and immediately preceded by the `/` character.